# Timeout when evaluating JS in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In my request spec (Webdriver spec), I have the following:

```
page.evaluate_script("$('#open-modal').click();")
```

It clicks the button, but then it times out once the modal is open. I get:

```
 Failure/Error: page.evaluate_script("$('#open-modal').click();")
 Timeout::Error:
   Timeout::Error
```

It uses a Twitter Bootstrap modal. How can I make it continue executing the spec / not timeout?

(the reason I can't just do `click_on` is because the element is offscreen)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
begin
  # Your spec
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts("I failed because of a timeout error")
  assert(false)
end
```

You can replace the `puts` statement with some code that spits out messages for whatever your testing framework is

Comment: This does prevent it from throwing the exception. Unfortunately, it still hangs for about a minute. Any idea how I can avoid the Timeout altogether?

Comment: I don't think you can do it simply.  You could maybe call a timing function, and set a variable that is checked in every function you want it to be.  You would have to use `Time.now` to set a variable, and then check that throughout your code.  I think it might be possible, but it would get very messy.  I would try to refactor the test so that it's not dependent on the javascript, and test the javascript with something like Jasmine